# Attach to process not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, web-applications

I've Web Application and for test need attach to process but when i click attach nothing happen and break point say:

> The break point will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Thanks for help

Comment: did you clear your solution and then rebuild it again?

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you do debugging? What you're attaching to, etc.? There could be many passes that lead to this issue

Comment: @HamedJavaheri,yes,i clean and rebuild solution butg dont work

Comment: @T.S.
i attach process to firefox or chrome

Comment: Dude, you have to attach to IIS worker process `wp3.exe`, not to web browser. ASP.NET app runs on server, not on client .

Comment: @T.S.
i try to attach to IIS but nothing happen

Comment: The problem is **-->** you have not provided any details in your question. I said, in my first comment **There could be many things that lead to this issue**. You need to follow this sequence: stop IIS pool, Clean out the temporary files from asp.net cache, start IIS pool, rebuild/deploy (with PDBs generated!/deployed), make sure your app runs(call default page?), attach

Comment: @T.S.
i have a web application and need to debug and but should use attach to process
i  set break point and attach to chrome/firefox/ie
visual studio go to debug mode but nothing happen and break point not hit and see on break point this :"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."
i try everything

Comment: Do I have to repeat myself? 4 days back I said, **DO NOT** attach to web browser. To debug ASP.NET application you need to attach to `wp3.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

1. Clean solution,
2. Rebuild,
3. Copy PDB files to target host in location where the deployed package is supposed to execute from